# How do I resolve 'undefined' is null or not an object error on my Google Map setup?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, internet-explorer-8, google-maps-api-3

I have this error while I am loading the Google map in IE8, but this is working in FF. Can anyone give me the solution to solve this problem?

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
>   Trident/4.0; chromeframe/13.0.782.112; chromeframe; .NET CLR
>   2.0.50727; InfoPath.2) Timestamp: Wed, 17 Aug 2011 05:06:11 UTC
>
> Message: 'undefined' is null or not an object
>   Line: 35 Char: 154 Code: 0 URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/6/0/main.js

Comment: Undefined is neither null, nor is it an object. Usually this error happens when something is undefined and you try to call a method or access a property on it... try running this with a debugger attached.

Comment: @wong2: and the loadin of the fiddle cause error in IE :)

Comment: If I were you I'd try finding out what line of code you are calling is causing this. and then post the relevant code here so that others might have a chance of helping.

Comment: This is the URL, http://optionsunited.com/index.php/helpful-links/clinics-in-los-angeles.html where i am working

Comment: I see an error in Chrome. You aren't setting the center of the Maps API v3 map that you construct. You should set it in MapOptions.